# Looking for pop up when a specific word is entered google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a VBA for excel that when a specific word is entered a pop up happens that says “make sure you did this step” I am very new to google sheets. (Our customer is requesting we use it instead of excel.) Is there a script that can do this in google sheets? I have looked and can’t find much and I unfortunately don’t have the time so I’m trying to learn on the fly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple trigger onEdit.  This function is automatically triggered when the user enters a value anywhere in the spreadsheet.  The event object "event" contains the range and value of the cell edited.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  if( event.value === "what word" ) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("make sure you did this step",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One quick question it works great when I type in the word but I notice the popup does not happen if I copy and paste the word from one cell to another. Is that just a quirk of sheets or is there a line I can input to make it activate when pasted in? It is usable either way I am just wondering. Again thank you.

Comment: onEdit will work with copy and paste but the event object value is only the upper left corner of the range that is copied.  so it that cell doesn't contain the word it won't trigger the alert